# how to use getdate() function in sql

Tags: sql

I am facing issue while using `getdate()` in sql query.

**query:**

```
select * from table where date_col < GETDATE()- 23;
```

**error:**

```
Getdate invalid identifier.
```

Could you please help me in resolving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what RDBMS you are using

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time...)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using..?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do something like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_col < DATEADD(DAY, -23, GETDATE());
```